# Get string byte length in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to find string byte length. Firstly convert to byte and then get the length so How can i get string byte length?

```
var
  val : String;
begin
  val:= 'example';
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(val) * ???)); -> BYTE LENGTH
end;
```

Comment: Or simply use [`ByteLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.ByteLength) if you have enough recent version of Delphi.

Comment: i am using xe6, thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var
  val : String;
begin
  val:= 'example';
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(val) * SizeOf(Char)));
end;
```

Or use `ByteLength` to obtain the size of a string in bytes. `ByteLength` calculates the size of the string by multiplying the number of characters in that string to the size of a character.

Comment: ByteLength accepts a UTF-16 string, so does funky things if you pass it ANSI or MBCS string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Please explain a bit further.

Comment: @KromStern: My bet: if you pass anything but a UTF-16 string, you'll first see a conversion to UnicodeString and then get the byte legnth of that, and not of the AnsiString, or UTF8String, or whatever it is you pass.

Comment: `ByteLength()` only accepts a `UnicodeString` as input, so anything passed to it is converted to UTF-16 (if not already) and it will then return the byte count in UTF-16 (as `Length(val) * SizeOf(WideChar)`).  If you want the byte length of a `UnicodeString` in another charset, use `TEncoding.GetEncoding(CodepageOrCharsetHere)` and `TEncoding.GetByteCount(UnicodeString)`.  Or use the `AnsiString(N)` type to convert `val` to a specific codepage and then use `Length(RawByteString)` to get its byte length regardless of what `N` is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Please post an answer!

Comment: Actually, UTF-16 can use more then two bytes per "character". As usual, Delphi implementation of whatever is lazy and incorrect.

Comment: Not sure this is the best way to go about it.
Some characters (asia, middle-east, sami and various other systems) can in some cases require 3 bytes for a char, then the next 2 bytes (and so on). I think you should manually do a for/next to be 100% sure you get it right

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden Remys answer is better. I would have deleted mine, but I can not until OP removes "accepted" flag.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`SysUtils.ByteLength()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.ByteLength) function:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  val : String;
begin
  val:= 'example';
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(ByteLength(val)));
end;
```

Just know that `ByteLength()` only accepts a `UnicodeString` as input, so any string passed to it, whether that be a `(Ansi|Wide|UTF8|RawByte|Unicode)String`, will be converted to UTF-16 (if not already) and it will then return the byte count in UTF-16, as simply `Length(val) * SizeOf(WideChar)`.

If you want the byte length of a `UnicodeString` in another charset, you can use the [`SysUtils.TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) class for that:

```
var
  val : String;
begin
  val := 'example';
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TEncoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(val)));
end;
```

```
var
  val : String;
  enc : TEncoding;
begin
  val := 'example';
  enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding(...); // codepage number or charset name
  try
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(enc.GetByteCount(val)));
  finally
    enc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, you can use the `AnsiString(N)` type to convert a `UnicodeString` to a specific codepage and then use `Length()` to get its byte length regardless of what `N` actually is:

```
type
  Latin1String = type AnsiString(28591); // can be any codepage supported by the OS...
var
  val : String;
  val2: Latin1String;
begin
  val := 'example';
  val2 := Latin1String(val);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(val2)));
end;
```